# Rails 6: some environment variables not loading via dotenv in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-dotenv

I'm creating a new application in Rails 6, and the workflow for keeping secrets in our other Rails apps (anywhere from 4.x and 5.2) was to create an `.env` file and import them through the `dotenv` gem, and then have `config/secrets` pull from the `ENV` hash.

However, when I run a console session in the R6 app and I try to access `ENV`, I see an **old** version where the variables I just added do not appear, while other variables I added last week **are** there. What's stranger is that if I run `rails c -e test`, `ENV` does include the new variables even though `.env.test` does not include them. (Meanwhile, `ENV` has all the variables when running through RSpec.)

Does anyone have ideas about this behavior? Should we consider using `credentials` instead?

EDIT: Well this is embarrassing: I rebooted my Macbook and now the ENV variables are updated.

Answer (score 2):

Happened the same to me, annoying. Could this be related to a specific `dotenv` loading issue? or maybe related to the underlying OS (`MacOS 10.15.7` in my case)?

Related issue: https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv/issues/308

Update: Tried `bin/spring stop` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62614109/171809) with no success

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the system in macOS Ventura 13.1 with an Intel chip worked for me.